# When I set up port forwarding on my home router, why does connecting to a local server via the public IP show the router's address as the client IP?

Tags: router, ip, routing, nat

I'm trying to understand how NAT works on a basic level within my home network (just a consumer Google Fiber router with no custom configuration other than the port forwarding I'm about to describe). I have a raspberry pi running a service on port 1234, and I have used the router's tools to set up port forwarding from 31234 on my public IP to port 1234 on my raspberry pi.

- (As expected) when I connect to the service from outside my home network (specifically, I tried connecting from a Digital Ocean VPS) using my home network's public IP, my raspberry pi server shows the Digital Ocean server's IP as the client IP of the connection.
- (As expected) when I connected to the service from within my home network (specifically, from my MacBook) using the raspberry pi's *internal* IP or hostname, my raspberry pi server shows my MacBook's local IP address (192.168.xx.xx).
- (**Unexpectedly**), when I connect to the service from within my home network (again, from my MacBook), using my home network's *public* IP, my raspberry pi shows the router's IP address (192.168.xx.1) as the client IP of the connection.

I am trying to understand why in the last case, the router's IP address is shown as the client IP, as opposed to other options that seem reasonable like my home network's public IP or my MacBook's local IP.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what would happen if the router did not do this. The local connection target would send its response traffic directly to your PC. However, your PC is expecting a response from the public IP address. The unrelated traffic would be discarded, communication would not be possible.

By putting the router as the connection source, response traffic would be sent back to it. The router would then know to forward the response to your PC.

Comment: This explains why it has to be an IP address assigned to the router, but not why it can't be the public IP address.